# How to check if a value is duplicate and if duplicate need to delete both line in Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, ado.net

I have a Datatable with few Line of Data, my aim is to check whether there is any Duplicate value and if there a duplicate line, i that Duplicate Value & i need to remove both lines that created duplicate.

Input

[image: InPut]

my expected Output would be

[image: OutPut]

Any Suggestion will be helpful

Thanks in Advance

Thanks & Regards
Harsha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way of getting a unique value for each row which depends only on the data in the row, this is usually known as a [hash value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Then you can use whatever method you like to [bin the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) and choose only the bins with one item.

For example, with just a DataGridView and a Button on a Form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Function RowHash(dr As DataRow) As Long
        'TODO: Make a hash function which will not overflow a Long.
        Dim h As Long = 0
        For Each itm In dr.ItemArray
            h = (31 * h) + itm.GetHashCode()
        Next

        Return h

    End Function

    Sub MakeTestData()
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        dt.Columns.Add("P")
        For i = 0 To 9
            Dim nr = dt.NewRow()
            nr("Name") = Chr(65 + (i Mod 6))
            nr("P") = i Mod 6
            dt.Rows.Add(nr)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newDataTable = dt.Clone()
        Dim uniqueData = dt.AsEnumerable().
            GroupBy(Function(r) RowHash(r)).
            Select(Function(s) New With {.n = s.Count, .data = s.First().ItemArray}).
            Where(Function(t) t.n = 1)

        For Each u In uniqueData
            Dim nr = newDataTable.NewRow()
            nr.ItemArray = u.data
            newDataTable.Rows.Add(nr)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = newDataTable

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MakeTestData()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Before and after clicking the button:

[image]